# Why is MediaPlayer failing?

Tags: android, audio, media-player

Here's the error:

```
09-12 22:13:05.253: ERROR/AudioFlinger(561): not enough memory for AudioTrack size=53560
09-12 22:13:05.253: ERROR/AudioTrack(561): AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12
09-12 22:13:05.253: ERROR/AudioSink(561): Unable to create audio track
09-12 22:13:05.253: ERROR/audiothread(561): Error creating AudioTrack
09-12 22:13:05.253: ERROR/PlayerDriver(561): Command PLAYER_PREPARE completed with an error or info PVMFFailure
09-12 22:13:05.253: ERROR/MediaPlayer(2368): error (1, -1)
```

What I am doing is-- instantiating a SoundFX object inside a base Activity (all other activities extend the base-- so they all share sound effects and sub menu).

Here's my SoundFX class:

```
public class SoundFX {
private SharedPreferences prefs = null;
private MediaPlayer[] sounds = null;

SoundFX(Context c){
    ValidateObject.isNotNull(c, "Null context.");

    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
    ValidateObject.isNotNull(prefs, "Null preferences.");

    sounds = new MediaPlayer[4];
    sounds[0] = MediaPlayer.create(c, R.raw.snd_button_menu);
    sounds[1] = MediaPlayer.create(c, R.raw.snd_button_direction);
    sounds[2] = MediaPlayer.create(c, R.raw.snd_button_text);
    sounds[3] = MediaPlayer.create(c, R.raw.snd_button_drill);
}

public void menu(){
    if (prefs.getBoolean("SoundFX", true)){
        sounds[0].start();
    }
}

public void direction(){
    if (prefs.getBoolean("SoundFX", true)){
        sounds[1].start();
    }
}

public void text(){
    if (prefs.getBoolean("SoundFX", true)){
        sounds[2].start();
    }
}
public void drill(){
    if (prefs.getBoolean("SoundFX", true)){
        sounds[3].start();
    }
}
}
```

This would be my "base" Activity which all activities extend:

```
public class ActivityWithMenu extends Activity {
protected SoundFX soundEffects = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     // no content view...
     soundEffects = new SoundFX(this);
     ValidateObject.isNotNull(soundEffects, "Null SoundFX Object.");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.submenu, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.submenu_hide:
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        return true;
    case R.id.submenu_help:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, HelpActivity.class));
        return true;
    case R.id.submenu_preferences:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Preferences.class));
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

}
```

Is each activity creating a new instance and thus allocating more memory? I can't seem to figure out why I would run out of memory. I was under the impression all child activities 
would use the same SoundFX object...

edit:

The error comes after creating and destroying around 10~12 activities. It works good before then.

Comment: Hehe, mr. Google, you should know your own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `release()` the media players before destroying the class (probably in `onDestroy` of your activity), otherwise the resources are not released (duh) and you soon get out of memory (since you allocate them again next time).

If you use those sounds in many activities, you can create a singletone, and avoid creating them each time you switch activity.

Comment: So I should have a releaseSoundFX method in SoundFX which releases all objects, and then override onDestory and call the method in each child activity?

Comment: I think I need to learn a bit more-- I think I was trying to create a singleton so I only had one instance. Where did I go wrong? :( By the way-- the onDestory method and releasing works great!